# How do I remove a laptop key on Sony Vaio PCG-3A1M?

Tags: keyboard

My 'E' key gets sometimes stuck, so I want to check the inside. How do I remove they key on my laptop?

Comment: If this isn't the correct layout for your keyboard YouTube will have plenty of other videos out there for you to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWzWCTD16nE

Comment: I just couldn't find a video exactly for my model. Is it the same for all PCG models?

Comment: Without signing in blood I suspect it will be. Generally speaking there isn't that much variation in keyboard connections for laptops. Getting them off is the same system (usually involving a screwdriver) then you can take a look at the connectors and see if it is the same as the video. If not find another one. It won't take you long.